# Regex for parenthesis and anything in between

Tags: r, regex

I've tried `(?<=\().*(?=\))`, but I don't know how to include the parenthesis. I don't think it accepts `/` as an escape character.

I'm trying to get rid of strings like these in a data.frame column:

```
" (50%)"
```

Not including the quotes - they are just to show that there is a space before the first `(`.

Desired output:

```
(50%)
```

I plan to do some heavy regex work this weekend, I keep getting stuck with it.

Comment: So, what is the problem? Remove a space before a `(` followed with any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, followed with `)`? What are the contexts? Can there be multiple `" (50%)"`s in the string?

Comment: Like this `(?<=\()[^)]*\)` or with the parentheses like this `\([^)]*\)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape character is `\`, not `/`. So `\(.*\)` should match. If you are using R, then you also need to write `" \\(.*\\)"` because you have to escape the `\` as well. This lets you literally match a space , both parentheses `(` and `)`, and then any characters between them.

```r
library(stringr)
str_detect(" (50%)", " \\(.*\\)")
#> [1] TRUE
```

Created on 2018-02-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).